# Помогите вычислить значение функции в Python

Tags: python, функции

Вычислить значения функции

```
y=arctg(x+1.23)/2Пи
```

На интервале для `x=[-2.2]` при изменении `x` с шагом `0.4`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте numpy

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.4)
y = np.arctan(x+1.23) / (2*np.pi)
```

Для отображения:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не делайте так, не отвечайте на вопросы, которые даже не пытались решить. Я обычно ставлю "голос против" на такие ответы, чтобы халяву не поддерживали, но вам пока не буду. ТС должен предоставить хоть  какой то базовый минимум своего решения или направление мыслей. Иначе SO превратится не в базу знаний на русском языке, а ресурс по решению домашних и лабораторных заданий

Comment: можно где-то связаться с вами длч уточнения?

Comment: @Dmitry, ну я думал, что у человека нет идей как это реализовать, поэтому помог и написал, что нужно для рассчёта и визуализации. Но, соглашусь, возможно стоило просто порекомендовать к изучению необходимый материал